# Is it possible to reduce $a^2+b^2 - 2Kab = 0 $ to some sort of a (a+b) (a-b) kind of equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

Is it possible to reduce $a^2+b^2 - 2Kab = 0 $
to some sort of a (a+b) (a-b) kind of equation? Or something that tells how a is related to b? The K is the spoiler being faced.

Comment: Not really anything to do with linear algebra. Tags edited.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you allow complex coefficients.

Hint: Factorize $x^2 - 2Kx + 1 $.
E.g. Calculate the roots using the quadratic formula.

Hence, factorize $a^2 - 2Kab + b^2$.